# Regular sequence in cohomology of Grassmannians

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

$\DeclareMathOperator\Gr{Gr}$Consider the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_m, y_1,\dots,y_n]$, I want to prove that the sequence $$x_1 + y_1, x_2 + x_1y_1 + y_2, \dots, x_my_{n-1} + x_{m-1}y_n, x_m y_n$$ is regular. Here the $k$th element is $\sum_{i} x_i y_{k-i}$ where $x_0=y_0=1$, $x_i=0$ for $i>m$, and $y_i = 0$ for $i>n$.

This question came up when trying to compute the cohomology ring $H^\ast(\Gr(m, m+n))$ of the (complex) Grassmannians. In particular, $x_i = c_i(\gamma)$ and $y_i = c_i(\gamma^\perp)$ correspond to Chern classes of the tautological bundle and its orthogonal complement, and the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_m, y_1,\dots,y_n]$ by the ideal generated by the above elements should be isomorphic to $H^\ast(\Gr(m, m+n))$. (Given this, one knows that the ring is finite as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, in particular it must have Krull dimension 1, hence the sequence is regular. But I want a more direct algebraic proof of this.)

My guess is that since the above elements are homogeneous (if we let $\deg x_i = i$), maybe one can compute the Hilbert series of the quotient. Or maybe one could set up some form of induction, but I couldn't get it to work yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modulo any prime ideal of the quotient ring, the product of polynomials

$$(1 + x_1 t + x_2 t^2 + \dots + x_m t^m) (1 + y_1 t + y_2 t^2 + \dots + y_n t^n ) $$ $$= 1 + (x_1+y_1) t + (x_2 + x_1 y_1 + y_2) t^2 + \dots + x_m y_n t^{n+m}$$

is equal to $1$. Since the quotient by a prime ideal is an integral domain, this forces both polynomials to equal $1$, so $x_1,\dots, x_m, y_1,\dots, y_n$ all lie in the ideal.

Hence the ring modulo the prime ideal is a quotient of $\mathbb Z$, i.e. either $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z/p$ for some $p$.

It follows that the Krull dimension is $1$ and the sequence is regular.